# Scikit-Learn Gaussian Mixture: How can log-probabilities be positive?

Tags: probability, clustering, python, scikit-learn, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am fitting a Gaussian Mixture model:
`gm = GaussianMixture(n_components=K)
gm.fit(features)`

When I do:

`gm.score_samples(features)`

All of the scores, which are supposed to be: "weighted log probabilities for each sample." are positive.
Are they actually log-probabilities?

Answer (score 7):

They supposedly are probability *densities*, not probabilities.

A probability density *can* be larger than 1, hence the log can be positive.

The documentation of sklearn should probably be fixed to reflect this.